# Multiple Spring WS Endpoints on different URL's

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I'm using Spring Boot and like in the example https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
WS Endpoints are exposed on /ws/* with *MessageDispatcher*:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

I want to have 2 endpoints on different URL's. Is that possible?